# NSPredicate to filter Core Data Relationship NSSet by attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `many-to-many` relationship with two entities. One is `Person`, the other is `Clubs`. I want to be able to write a `predicate` that will find all `Person` entities that are in a specific `Club`. I also want to check that person's `position` attribute.

Here is what isn't working:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND IN %@", @"manager", self.clubs.people]];
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

This crashes with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "title CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND IN %@"'

I know I am doing something wrong here, any help?

Comment: Try using SELF to refer to the Person object itself, rather than an attribute: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF IN %@", @"manager", self.clubs.people]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @pbasdf above, you should use self. However, the query would be much more efficient with the self clause first i.e.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ AND position CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.clubs.people, @"manager"];
```